# How to reset a qemu VM and let it freeze at the start?

Tags: qemu

I am using `qemu-system-arm` to emulate an ARM VM.

I can use the `-S` option to freeze the CPU at the very beginning.

And I can use the `system_reset` command from the `<qemu>` prompt to reset the system.

But it seems the `system_reset` cannot freeze the CPU at the very beginning just like the `-S`.

Is there any way to achieve the **combined effect**?

(I am new to qemu and I searched for a while. Excuse me if this is a dumb question.)

Answer (score 0):

The simple `stop` command should do.